# Search by results of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

What is correct way to use query like this one?

```
 SELECT Project_name,
  FROM [Table 1]
  WHERE Project_id in
      (SELECT ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, ID_4, ID_5
       FROM [Table 2])
```

i.e. to search by select result of 2 and more columns

Comment: Your query, in general, won't even run, if `[Table 2]` has more than one row.  Maybe show us some data which better explain what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `apply`:

```
  SELECT Project_name,
  FROM [Table 1]
  WHERE Project_id in
  (SELECT v.value FROM [Table 2]
   cross apply (values(ID_1), 
                      (ID_2), 
                      (ID_3), 
                      (ID_4), 
                      (ID_5))v(value))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

From your question, you can try to use `exists` instead of `in`

if this query didn't hit your expect.

Could you provide some sample data, expect result, more explanation on your question let it clear.

```
SELECT Project_name,
FROM [Table 1]
WHERE exists
(
select 1 FROM [Table 2]
WHERE Project_id = ID_1 or 
      Project_id = ID_2 or
      Project_id = ID_3 or
      Project_id = ID_4 or
      Project_id = ID_5 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Unpivot on second table.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #PROJECTS(ID INT IDENTITY,NAME VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #PROJECTS
VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G')

CREATE TABLE #PROJECT_DETAIL(ID INT IDENTITY, P1 INT,P2 INT,P3 INT )
INSERT INTO #PROJECT_DETAIL
VALUES(1,4,5),(2,5,2),(3,1,4)
```

Now do unpivot `#PROJECT_DETAIL` and use unpivoted ID column in `IN` Operator.

```
SELECT * FROM #PROJECTS
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT PROJECT_IDS FROM #PROJECT_DETAIL
UNPIVOT
(
    PROJECT_IDS FOR PROJECTS IN ([P1],[P2],[P3])
)UP
)
```

**Result:**

```
ID  NAME
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```